# One-way "cross" of function between two matrices

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I'm trying to create a sort of one way "cross" of a function between two matrices, such that every pair in one matrix is mapped to every pair in the other, but not the other way around; for example, given the two matrixes:

```
matrixA = {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 2}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 0}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}} (* Tuples[{0, 1, 2}, 2 *)
matrixB = {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}} (* Tuples[{0, 1}, 2] *)
```

I want to compute: *[edited - I forgot the closing brace]*

```
{f[{{0, 0}, {0, 0}}], f[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}}], f[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}], f[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}], 
 f[{{0, 1}, {0, 0}}], f[{{0, 1}, {0, 1}}], f[{{0, 1}, {1, 0}}], f[{{0, 1}, {1, 1}}],
 f[{{1, 0}, {0, 0}}], f[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}], f[{{1, 0}, {1, 0}}], f[{{1, 0}, {1, 1}}],
 f[{{1, 1}, {0, 0}}], f[{{1, 1}, {0, 1}}], f[{{1, 1}, {1, 0}}], f[{{1, 1}, {1, 1}}]}
```

How do I do this? I've fiddled with Inner, Outer, MapThread, etc, but haven't been able to get what I want.

For reference, this is the snippet I'm trying to use this in:

```
dim = base^num + 1;
mat = ConstantArray[0, {dim, dim}];
mat[[dim, dim]] = 1;
tuples = Tuples[{0, 1}, num];
p := (frac[[1]]^Count[rev, 1] * minusfrac^Count[rev, 0])/(frac[[2]]^num);
z := MapThread[If[#2 == 0, #1, 0] &, {state[[i + 1]], rev}];
state = Tuples[Range[0, base - 1], num]
For[i = 0, i < dim - 1, i++,
 Do[
  mat[[i + 1, FromDigits[z, base] + 2]] += p, {rev, tuples}
 ]
]
```

I'm just trying to simplify this by pre-computing `z` for all values of `i` and `rev` so that I can hopefully get a step closer to doing away entirely with the `for` and `do` loops. If you find a more effective way to simplify this snippet than the route I'm trying to take [or if my reasoning is flawed], please tell me!

Comment: Your expected result is incomplete and your code snippet has undefined symbols, so I don't really have a way to check anything. But I *think* you might be looking for `Outer[f, matrixA, matrixB, 1]`.

Comment: That doesn't match exactly, but I assume it's close enough for you to work with. Maybe you want `f@*List` instead of just `f`. And of course you can flatten it.

Comment: `f /@ Tuples[{matrixA, matrixB}]`?

Comment: also `Distribute[f[matrixA, matrixB], List, f, List, f@*List]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Intersection`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Intersection.html) and [`Tuples`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples.html).

With

```
matrixA = Tuples[{0, 1, 2}, 2];
matrixB = Tuples[{0, 1}, 2];
```

Then

```
f /@ Tuples[Intersection[matrixA, matrixB], 2]
```

> ```
> {f[{{0, 0}, {0, 0}}], f[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}}], f[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}], f[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}], 
>  f[{{0, 1}, {0, 0}}], f[{{0, 1}, {0, 1}}], f[{{0, 1}, {1, 0}}], f[{{0, 1}, {1, 1}}], 
>  f[{{1, 0}, {0, 0}}], f[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}], f[{{1, 0}, {1, 0}}], f[{{1, 0}, {1, 1}}], 
>  f[{{1, 1}, {0, 0}}], f[{{1, 1}, {0, 1}}], f[{{1, 1}, {1, 0}}], f[{{1, 1}, {1, 1}}]}
> ```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You get almost the right thing using Map and Outer, but it has an extra { } around it.

```
matrixA = Tuples[{0, 1, 2}, 2];
matrixB = Tuples[{0, 1}, 2];
m = Map[f, Outer[List, matrixA, matrixB, 1], {2}]
```

You remove the extra { } with

```
Flatten[m,1]
```

Answer (score 0):

A oneliner:

```
Sort[(x |-> f[#, x] & /@ Select[matrixA , (Max@# < 2 &)]) /@ matrixB //
    Flatten, ({10, 1} . #1[[1]] <= {10, 1} . #2[[1]] &)] // TableForm

f[{0,0},{0,0}]
f[{0,0},{0,1}]
f[{0,0},{1,0}]
f[{0,0},{1,1}]
f[{0,1},{0,0}]
f[{0,1},{0,1}]
f[{0,1},{1,0}]
f[{0,1},{1,1}]
f[{1,0},{0,0}]
f[{1,0},{0,1}]
f[{1,0},{1,0}]
f[{1,0},{1,1}]
f[{1,1},{0,0}]
f[{1,1},{0,1}]
f[{1,1},{1,0}]
f[{1,1},{1,1}]
```